# how to transform two for loops into array method

Tags: typescript, for-loop, foreach, array.prototype.map

```
const mergeResults = async (items: string[]): Promise<MyArray[]> => {
  let itemsArray = []

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let itemsFilter = await testMyData(items[i])
   for(let j = 0; j < itemsFilter.length; j++) {
       itemsArray.push(itemsFilter[j])
   }
}
  return itemsArray;
};
```

I intend to transform this part of the code into:

.map or .forEach method

```
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let itemsFilter = await testMyData(items[i])
   for(let j = 0; j < itemsFilter.length; j++) {
       itemsArray.push(itemsFilter[j])
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an asynchronous request for each item in `items`, and need to wait for the resolution of each such request, so `.map` in combination with `Promise.all` would be more appropriate, *if* the `testMyData` function can handle it. You only need a `items.map(testMyData)` to get an array of Promises, and then `.flat()` to flatten the values afterwards.

```
const mergeResults = async (items: string[]): Promise<MyArray[]> => {
    const nestedResults = await Promise.all(items.map(testMyData));
    return nestedResults.flat();
};
```

That said, note that this invokes `testMyData` many times synchronously - in contrast, your original code invokes it only in serial, after the last iteration's test has completed. Running in parallel has the potential to be much faster, but it also has the potential to overload whatever resources `testMyData` requires, so be aware.

The return type of `MyArray[]` doesn't sound quite right. The logic being performed is to convert an asynchronously retrieved 2D array of test results into a flat array of results. Unless each test result is an array itself, calling a single result a `MyArray` sounds misleading. Perhaps call that type `TestResult` instead, so that you have `Promise<TestResult[]>`.